# Advance text style of feature in openlayers

Tags: openlayers, style, features

Is there any way to create table or any html element in text style for features? i tried other ways like putting overlay on feature then in overlay i used table and html elements but had some problems with it also control of overlays to disable and enable on map for each feature was hard.

Answer (score 1):

It uses canvas text operations so HTML elemensts are not possible https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text (but text wrapping using \n is supported, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-labels.html).  If you need to produce a table effect you would need an array of styles using offsetX and offsetY and the appropriate text for each entry, for example https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-layer-2n47l